# Cannot display in hexadecimal

Tags: c++

```
unsigned int i = 0x02081;
cout << std::hex << i;
```

This displays 2081 when compiled with VS2010 but I think it should display 0x02081. Am I right, and if so, how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default the base is not printed:

```
cout << std::hex << std::showbase << i;
```

Answer (score 7):

The easiest solution, of course, is:

```
cout << "0x" << std::hex << i;
```

Leading zeroes can vary in amount because they don't matter. You can choose any amount you like.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Why not, if that's what you want?  Why use some complicated mechanism, when there is a simple solution.

Comment: @James Because the simple solution is using the `showbase` stream manipulator.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be And, of course, to restore it after the output, since you don't want to leave the stream in a permanently modified state?  But since when is indirectly invoking a function through a somewhat complex mechanism simpler than just using a constant?  And what if the value was 0x1BA3, and that was the desired output?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be you should only downvote truly misleading answers that do not answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 6):

> I think it should display 0x02081. Am
>   I right

No, you're not.  It will display the value in hex, which is `2081`.  The `0x` isn't part of the number, per se, it's just a notational convenience.  The leading zero is also not a part of the number.

If you want the exact output you said you expected, you can do this:

```
cout << std::hex << std::showbase << std::setw(5) << std::setfill('0') << i;
```

Comment: +1 for `setw()` and `setfill()` but -1 for manual printing of base

Answer (score 0):

It should display the value of `i` as a hexadecimal number - and does so. The prefix `0x` is just something *some* programming languages use to indicate that a literal should be considered hexadecimal.

```
cout << "0x" << std::hex << i;
```

As Let_Me_Be points out: `"0x" << std::hex` could be replaced with `std::hex << std::showbase` if you want automatic printing of 0x/0/nothing for hex/octal/decimal.